# Measuring heart rate and hacking an exercise machine to extend the grip area

Tags: sensor

Most of you are probably familiar with exercise machines that have grips for each hand so that you can take your heart rate.

Imagine one for a skiing type of device...with the metal measuring grips on the 'poles' that you push/pull back and forth.

Do you think that we can retrofit it and replace the metal grips with a larger piece of metal that runs the most of the length of the ski pole without interfering with the measuring electronics?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure on this but I think the answer is yes.

The sensor would work by measuring the tiny difference in voltage between the left hand and the right hand.

You could prove that retrofitting a larger piece of metal to the poles would work by simply wrapping the poles with aluminium foil. If it still works and successfully measures your heart rate from you touching the foil which in turn touches the existing metal pads, then I think you can safely say that the retrofit would work.